# Cannot return a float value of -1.00

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently doing an assignment for a computer science paper at university. I am in my first year.

in one of the questions, if the gender is incorrect the function is suppose to return a value of -1. But in the testing column, it says the expected value is -1.00. And I cannot seem to be able to return the value of '-1.00', it will always return a value of -1.0 (with one zero). I used the .format to make the value 2sf (so it will appear with two zero's) but when converting it to a float the value always returns "-1.0".

```
return float('{:.2f}'.format(-1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn’t as clear as it could be. Does your instructor or testing
software expect a string `'-1.00'`? If so, just return that. Is a
`float` type expected? Then return `-1.0`; the number of digits shown does
not affect the value.

Comment: Yeah i am sorry about my explanation. Was feeling rushed and frustrated at the time. But now all is resolved thanks to your comment! Wish I had just simply known the number of digits shown doesn't affect the value earlier.

Comment: どうもありがとう, glad it was useful :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you have done, but i had tried this way and output what you expect.

```
    b = -1    
    >>> print("%.2f" % (b))
    -1.00
    >>> print("%.2f" % (-1))
    -1.00
```

Answer (score 0):

What does the following code do?

```
print(float('{:.2f}'.format(-1)))
```

The `'{:.2f}'.format(-1)` creates some string representation of `-1.` defined by the format string. The `float(...)` converts this string  to the float `1.` The print command converts this float to a sting, using some default format, and prints this string to the screen. I think that isn't what you expected because the format you used does not effect the print command in formatting the string.
I assume you want

```
print('{:.2f}'.format(float(-1)))
```

and this actually does what you want, it prints

```
1.00
```

http://ideone.com/GyINQR

It is not necessary to convert `-1` explicitely  to  `float`

```
print('{:.2f}'.format(-1))
```

gives the desired result:
http://ideone.com/U2RTMX